# VueJS not reacting when backs page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

The `mounted()` hook is not called when I back to the page so I can't change objects to react on screen.

Scenario with 2 pages:

1. **PageA** to **PageB** // `mounted()`'s **PageB** is called.
2. Back to **PageA**
3. Go to **PageB** again // `mounted()`'s **PageB** is not called.

I really need the invoke hook because I must change a value on component. I know that Vue try cache the last page, but in this case I must use hooks every navitation.

Comment: Tried the `created` hook?

Comment: yes, `created()` is not called too... and `update()` is not called too.

Comment: You could try to use a `watch` on `$route` and when it changes to your PageB route calling your code block

Comment: Yes, ` watch: {
    '$route' ... } ` is called but the changes not reacting on the components.